# Optimising a Prolog Program (remove duplicates, repeat recalculation)

Tags: prolog

I am very inexperienced with Prolog. I have a data set that contains elements and relations in graph that has circularity (quite a lot). There are rules to calculate the summary relation of a path. One of these is: one takes the path, then takes the weakest relation, and that is the one that holds between both ends.

With 
Elements `E1`, `E2`, `E3` and
Relations `R1/R1c`, `R2`, `R3` (strength low to high) and
structure `E1-R3-E2`, `E1-R1-E2`, `E2-R2-E3`, `E3-R1-E2`

I can make the following minimal example:

```
% weaker table
isWeaker( r1, r2).
isWeaker( r2, r3).
weaker( X, Y) :- isWeaker( X, Y).
weaker( X, Y) :-
    isWeaker( X, Z),
    weaker( Z, Y).
% 'weakest' is <= not <
weakest( X, X, Y) :- =(X,Y).
weakest( X, X, Y) :- weaker( X, Y).

% All direct relations
isADirectRelation( e1, r1, e2).
isADirectRelation( e1, r3, e2).
isADirectRelation( e2, r2, e3).
isADirectRelation( e3, r1, e2).
isADirectRelation( e1, r3, e4).
isADirectRelation( e4, r2, e3).
isADirectRelation( e1, r1, e4).
isADirectRelation( e3, r1, e4).

% derived relations calculations

% Structural Chains
isADerivedRelation( Source, Relation, Target, Visited) :-
    \+ member( [Source,Relation,Target], Visited),
    weakest( Relation, RelationOne, RelationTwo),
    isARelation( Source, RelationOne, Intermediate, [[Source,Relation,Target]|Visited]),
    isARelation( Intermediate, RelationTwo, Target, [[Source,Relation,Target]|Visited]).

% major workhorse with anti-circularity
isARelation( Source, Relation, Target, Visited) :-
    (isADirectRelation( Source, Relation, Target);
     isADerivedRelation( Source, Relation, Target, Visited)).
```

The result of `isARelation( Source, Relation, Target, []).` is

```
e1,r1,e2
e1,r3,e2
e2,r2,e3
e3,r1,e2
e1,r3,e4
e4,r2,e3
e1,r1,e4
e3,r1,e4

e1,r1,e3
e3,r1,e3
e1,r1,e3 duplicate
e3,r1,e3 duplicate
```

Missing are

```
e4,r1,e4
e2,r2,e2
```

Is it at all possible to solve this in Prolog? Formally, yes, of course, but also with a decent performance?

Comment: Are you sure Prolog is the language\tool to use?

Comment: One small observation: the `\+ member([Source,Relation,Target], Visited)` call at the beginning of `isADerivedRelation/4` is redundant with the one in `isARelation/4`, assuming `isADerivedRelation/4` is also otherwise only called from places that already check it. I'm also curious as to why you write, `=(X, Y)` rather than `X = Y`, or even more simply, `weakest(X, X, X).` instead of `weakest( Weakest, X, Y) :- =(Weakest, X), =(X,Y).`, and `weakest(X, X, Y) :- weaker(X, Y).` instead of `weakest( Weakest, X, Y) :- =(Weakest, X), weaker( X, Y).`.

Comment: The \+member call at the start of isARelation/4 has been removed, it was blocking the valid e1,r1,e3 result. I write it that way as I am inexperienced... I am not sure Prolog is the right tool, but I'm trying to find out. If it works, it would be much easier to maintain as I just have to write the rules.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with using Prolog for this kind of problem. I haven't had time to really comb through your logic for optimization. But pruning is always what one does by the very nature of the logic (applying progressive conditions to narrow down the solution set). You want to try to get your "big hitters" early on to narrow down quickly.

Comment: Thanks lurker. Changed the example, it now has both missing results and duplicates.

Comment: BTW, if someone can tell me how to use setof/3 to create a statement that will give me all the solutions? I only can find information about a single thing, but I need 
e1,r3,e2
e2,r2,e3
e3,r1,e2 etc. setof(???, isARelation(Source, Relation,Target,[]), List). maybe?

Comment: The trick with `setof/3` is basically that the first argument is an example of what you want to collect from all the times the second argument gets evaluated. The third argument is the result. So you could do `setof((Source,Relation,Target), isARelation(Source, Relation,Target,[]), List)` and you would get a list of comma separated stuff per your example. (It would be more idiomatic to separate with `-`.)

Answer (score 1):

There are many things to be said about this question, so this will be a long and rambling and ultimately unsatisfactory answer. So I might as well start with a pet peeve: Please don't use `camelCaseIdentifiers` for predicates, we usually use `underscore_separated_words` instead. I'm not sure why this bugs me in Prolog in particular, but I suspect partly because uppercase letters are syntactically significant.

Moving on, your `weakest/3` predicate is broken:

```
?- weakest(Weakest, r2, r1).
false.
```

I think you had this right in the first version of your question, but then you removed the third clause of `weakest/3` because you thought it caused redundant answers. Needless to say, "efficiency" is useless without correctness. (Also, we usually put the "output" arguments last, not first.)

Part of the reason you get redundant answers is your use of two (indirectly) recursive calls to `isARelation/4` in `isADerivedRelation/4`. What you are computing is something like the transitive closure of the union of "direct" relations. The usual way to express the transitive closure in Prolog is like this:

```
transitive_closure(A, B) :-
    base_relation(A, B).
transitive_closure(A, C) :-
    base_relation(A, B),
    transitive_closure(B, C).
```

That is, we first "take a base step", then recurse. If our base relation has pairs `a-b`, `b-c`, `c-d`, then this will find the solution `a-d` exactly once, as the composition of the base pair `a-b` and the derived transitive pair `b-d`. In contrast, if we were to structure the second clause as you did, with two recursive calls to `transitive_closure/2`, we would get the solution `a-d` twice: Once as above, but also once because we would derive the transitive pair `a-c` and compose it with `c-d` to give `a-d`.

You can fix this by changing your first `isARelation/4` call in `isADerivedRelation/4` into a call to `isADirectRelation/3`.

Another problem is that you are using `Visited` wrong: You are marking the pair `Source-Target` as visited before you have proved that such a solution even exists! You should probably mark `Source-Intermediate` as visited instead.

Even so, you will still get redundant solutions for a pair of elements if there are several different paths between those elements in the graph. This is just how Prolog's logic works: Prolog finds individual answers to your query but does not allow you to talk directly about relationships between those answers. If we want to force it to enumerate everything exactly once, we must leave pure logic.

Some Prolog systems offer a feature called "tabling" which essentially caches all the solutions for a "tabled" predicate and avoids re-computations. This should avoid redundant answers and even simplify your definition: If your closure relation is tabled, you no longer need to track a `Visited` list because cyclic recomputations will be avoided by the tabling. I can't give you tested code because I have no Prolog with tabling lying around. Even without tabling offered by your system, there is the theoretical possibility of "memoizing" solutions yourself, using Prolog's impure database. It's difficult to get it exactly right with no redundant solutions whatsoever.

As an alternative to impure Prolog, your problem seems a better fit to [datalog](/questions/tagged/datalog) or [answer-set-programming](/questions/tagged/answer-set-programming). These are programming models that use Prolog-like syntax but with set semantics that seems to be exactly what you want: A proposition is either a solution or not, there is no concept of redundant solutions. The entire set of solutions is computed in one go. Cycle elimination is also automatic, so you don't need (in fact, because of the restricted input language, cannot use) a `Visited` list. If I were you, I would try to do this in Datalog.

As a further Prolog extension, there might be a spiffy solution based on Constraint Handling Rules (CHR). But really, do try Datalog.

Finally, I don't see why you think that `e2,r2,e2` is a missing solution. The only path from `e2` to `e2` that I see goes through `e3` and back to `e2` via an `r1` relation, which is the weakest one, so the solution should be `e2,r1,e2`.

Comment: Thank you Isabelle. I was close to putting my own answer (as I had fixed my stuff and it now works correctly, though it doesn't scale (as you point out). Luckily I saw your answer first. I was wondering that I have 4 combinations: WeakestOne,DirectOne,Two,WeakestTwo,DirectOne,Two, WeakestOne,One,DirectTwo, WeakestTwo,DirectOne,Two, but I think not, as there should be no difference in 'rolling up' the route from one end or the other.

Comment: I cannot use Source,Target for marking as multiple relations between any two elements can exist. If I have tried one, I can still get another derived relation with the other one. As the example shows. And you're right, e2,r2,e2 is not valid, I made a mistake.

Comment: I wonder: can I use datalog? Are e1,r1,e3 and e1,r2,e3 considered to be redundant solutions? I need both solutions.

Comment: I'm not a Datalog expert, but yes, you will get both solutions in this case. They would not be considered redundant because they are not the same term. BTW, if you have fixed the correctness of your code and maybe even some of the performance-related things, you could update your question with the new code, and maybe someone will give more tips.

Comment: I thought I let the question stand, because the answers (such as yours) make little sense if the question is fixed. So I uploaded it as an answer instead.

Comment: BTW, I've been thinking indeed about a 'Found" list that would contain Found valid results. How would that best be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up with, thanks to also the comments by Lurker and answer by Isabelle is this:

```
% weaker table
isWeaker( r1, r2).
isWeaker( r2, r3).
weaker( X, Y) :- isWeaker( X, Y).
weaker( X, Y) :-
    isWeaker( X, Z),
    weaker( Z, Y).
% 'weakest' is <= not <
weakest( X, X, Y) :- =(X,Y).
weakest( X, X, Y) :- weaker( X, Y).

% All direct relations
isADirectRelation( e1, r1, e2).
isADirectRelation( e1, r3, e2).
isADirectRelation( e2, r2, e3).
isADirectRelation( e3, r1, e2).
isADirectRelation( e1, r3, e4).
isADirectRelation( e4, r2, e3).
isADirectRelation( e1, r1, e4).
isADirectRelation( e3, r1, e4).

% derived relations calculations

isARelation( Source, Relation, Target, _) :-
    isADirectRelation( Source, Relation, Target).

% Structural Chains
isARelation( Source, Relation, Target, Visited) :-
    \+ member( [Source,Relation,Target], Visited),
    weakest( Relation, RelationOne, RelationTwo),
    isADirectRelation( Source, RelationOne, Intermediate),
    isARelation( Intermediate, RelationTwo, Target, [[Source,RelationOne,Intermediate]|Visited]).
isARelation( Source, Relation, Target, Visited) :-
    \+ member( [Source,Relation,Target], Visited),
    weakest( Relation, RelationOne, RelationTwo),
    isADirectRelation( Source, RelationTwo, Intermediate),
    isARelation( Intermediate, RelationOne, Target, [[Source,RelationTwo,Intermediate]|Visited]).

write_relation( Result) :-
    write( Result), nl.

writeAllRelations :-
   setof( (Relation, Source, Target), Relation^isARelation( Source, Relation, Target, []), ListOfAllRelations),
% maplist( write_relation, ListOfAllRelations). % For SWIProlog
write( ListOfAllRelations). % for JIProlog
```

This works and produces he right outcome:

```
r1,e1,e2
r1,e1,e3
r1,e1,e4
r1,e2,e2
r1,e2,e3
r1,e2,e4
r1,e3,e2
r1,e3,e3
r1,e3,e4
r1,e4,e2
r1,e4,e3
r1,e4,e4
r2,e1,e3
r2,e2,e3
r2,e4,e3
r3,e1,e2
r3,e1,e4
```

However, in the real world, with 60 or so entities and 800 or so direct relations, I've not found a Prolog that can handle it. I'll look into Datalog.